# Why won't this SQL code in Python make a tuple?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm creating a python program that needs to retrieve data from a .db file. I want to make a tuple that would be like this: (city, number of cases, sex, number of cases per sex, symptom, number of cases per symptom)

I thought that this:

```py
sql = 'SELECT CityMun, COUNT(CaseCode) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun, SELECT Sex COUNT(Sex) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun,Sex, SELECT SymptomType, COUNT(SymptomType) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun,SymptomType'
data = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
```

Would work, but this error message pops up:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SELECT": syntax error

I've also tried

```py
sql = 'SELECT CityMun, COUNT(CaseCode) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun'
data = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()

sql = 'SELECT Sex, COUNT(Sex) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun,Sex'
sex = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()

sql = 'SELECT SymptomType, COUNT(SymptomType) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun,SymptomType'
symptom = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()
```

but I really want them to be in just 1(?) tuple,

for example:
(City A, 1234, Female, 56, Male, 67, Asymptomatic, 145, Died, 356, Symptomatic, 638)

Is this possible?

Comment: The first statement has comma delimited statements. The statement terminator in T-SQL is a semi-colon (`;`). T-SQL doesn't have "tuples", you can't have datasets of datasets.

Comment: What's preventing you from creating a tuple yourself from the data you've fetched?

Comment: @OctaveL thank you! I think this would work. I'm going to try this.

Comment: SQL Server != SQLite

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a list, not a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert list into tuple like following:-

```
sql = 'SELECT CityMun, COUNT(CaseCode) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun'
data = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()

sql = 'SELECT Sex, COUNT(Sex) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun,Sex'
sex = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()

sql = 'SELECT SymptomType, COUNT(SymptomType) FROM CovidCases GROUP BY CityMun,SymptomType'
symptom = cursor.execute(sql).fetchall()

print(tuple(data) + tuple(sex) + tuple(symptom))
```

Comment: Thank you! I've created a tuple with the data I was given :)